# Variant on `PrimeZetaP`

Tags: functions, summation, prime-numbers

Mathematica has [`PrimeZetaP`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrimeZetaP.html) for the prime zeta function $\sum_p \frac{1}{p^s}$ where the sum is taken over all primes.

How do I use Mathematica to make an equivalent summation that runs over all primes that are plus or minus `6` from another prime? In other words,

$$\sum_{{q,q\pm 6}\in\mathbb{P}} \frac{1}{q^s}$$

Comment: Anything known about this function at all?

Comment: I think I’m kind of inventing it... But I’m just wondering how I’d code it :-)

Comment: I think you need to get an analytical expression for it (in the mathematical sense, e.g., a series, an integral, etc.). Well, you've got a series, but it's not a very convenient one.  You could loop over the primes, but I suspect `PrimeZetaP` does not do that (maybe it does it for large values of `s`).  Is anything known about a similar sum over twin primes?

Comment: Only that the sum converges to Brun’s constant which lies somewhere between (roughly) $1.8$ and $2.4$.

Comment: It should depend on `s`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, just as `PrimeZetaP` and `Zeta` depend on `s`. It’s a function of `s` that I’m aiming for - the sum to infinity of the reciprocals of all primes of that type raised to power `s`..,